# use any webfont with google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webfonts, google-webfonts

By default Google Sheets support 6 fonts only.

This can be further extended by "35 Fonts" add-on.

I wonder if I could actually use any webfont, ie. by setting it programmatically using custom Google Apps script/function?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for, but [.setFontFamily(fontFamily)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFontFamily(String)) is the method you're looking for if you're looking to sets fonts in Sheets using Apps script.

How many font families this supports, I don't know, but I imagine that's what the [more fonts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/more-fonts/jcknpndapmfpoepnpnimalmnjbmhofij?hl=en) add on uses.

Comment: sure, but my question was about webfonts so it really boils down to be able to include web fonturl through css like here http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine            , see more here: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started